# Dart GetX Unexpected Null Value when refreshed

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-getx

I redirected my Home View page to another view.

```
class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return CustomScaffold(
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Get.to(() => AirView());
          },
          child: Text("GO NEXT"),
        ),
);
```

After going to the next page, i encounter an error when I REFRESH the page.
[image]

No Directionality used.

[image]

**Console Error**

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building Directionality(textDirection: ltr):
Unexpected null value.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Directionality
Directionality:file:///C:/Flutter/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.5/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:328:12
..\…\root\get_material_app.dart:328
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49      throw*
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 528:63  nullCheck
packages/get/get_navigation/src/routes/route_middleware.dart 199:50                                                            page
packages/get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart 347:23                                                              initialRoutesGenerate
packages/flutter/src/widgets/app.dart 1559:27                                                                                  
packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 3290:41                                                                            restoreState
packages/flutter/src/widgets/restoration.dart 887:5                                                                            [_doRestore]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/restoration.dart 873:7                                                                            didChangeDependencies
packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 3336:11                                                                            didChangeDependencies
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4963:11                                                                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                                                             mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                                                                            inflateWidget
......

**Second Page Codes**:

```
  const AirView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AircoView'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'AirView is working',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please share console error you are getting.

Comment: where did you use `Directionality`?

Comment: @mohammadesmaili Didnt use.

Comment: did you use `GetMaterialApp` as root?

Comment: @mohammadesmaili yeap,
 runApp(
    GetMaterialApp(
      title: "Application",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
      getPages: AppPages.routes,
    ),
  );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue.

Used get_cli: ^1.8.1 Package

- https://pub.dev/packages/get_cli

then use this command: get create page:airco on home

This will then automatically generate Children under GetPage in the file app_pages.dart

```
GetPage(
      name: _Paths.HOME,
      page: () => const HomeView(),
      binding: HomeBinding(),
 children: [
        GetPage(
          name: _Paths.AIRCO,
          page: () => const AircoView(),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Paths is from app_routes (automatically created by Get CLI package as well)

Answer (score 0):

you are not using `materialapp` because you are using `getmaterialapp` than you have to wrap your `Directionality` in `mediaquery` like this.

```
    import 'dart:ui' as ui;
    ...
    new MediaQuery(
        data: new MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window),
        child: new Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: new MyHome())))
```

Comment: Where should i add this block of codes? at elevated Button?

Comment: I can't see Directionality in your code but in error, it's there. so where ever you're using Directionality put mediaquery widget above it.

Comment: I didnt use any Directionality @ManishDayma

Comment: please share the code to reproduce.

Comment: The above codes reproduces the error, Get.to -> to a GetView page, and then refresh

Answer (score 0):

wrap getbuilder inside getbuilder

see mycode :

```
GetBuilder<HomeController>(
        init: HomeController(),
        initState: (_) {},
        builder: (_) {
          return GetBuilder<HomeController>(
            builder: (controller) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: const Text('Footware Admin'),
                  centerTitle: true,
                ),
                body: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: const Text('Title'),
                      subtitle: const Text('Price : 100'),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.testMethod();
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.add)),
              );
            },
          );
        });
```